# The emulator process for AVD Pixel_2_API_30 has terminated error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

When I try to run the virtual emulator in Android Studio, I get the error The emulator process for AVD Pixel_2_API_30 has terminated

Answer (score 0):

Delete all virtual devices on Device Manager just in case.
Then go to Android Studio installation folder.You will see two folders named "jbr" and "jre".

Copy whole content of "jbr" to "jre" folder.

Now you can create new virtual devices on Android Studio and run them without any issue.